# как запустить внешний файл exe из vbs скрипта?

Tags: exe, vbscript

Как запустить файл exe изнути vbs скрипта?

то есть есть скрипт и нужно что-бы он запускал программу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe""")
Set objShell = Nothing
```