# Запуск модуля .py из другого vbs скрипта

Tags: python, vbscript

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как запустить модуль .py из скрипта vbs. Фрагмент кода по ссылке [как запустить внешний файл exe из vbs скрипта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1080474/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-exe-%d0%b8%d0%b7-vbs-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0) требует объект Wscript и не работает.
Требуется сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run(path_rg2 & "\repo.py")
```

Comment: Вот старая заметка, но может поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732543/running-python-script-using-wshshell-run-in-vbs-does-not-generate-output-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upd. Решил с помощью ссылки из комментария. Добавлю код.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
python = "python "
cmd = "C:\macro\repo.py"
objShell.Run (python & cmd)
```

Объекту WScript.Shell нужно передать ссылку на интерпретатор (при добавлении в path можно писать просто python) и через пробел указать путь до исполняемого файла с расширением и без пробелов в пути.